# Anime.js stop animation when scrolling stops

Tags: javascript, animation, scroll, anime.js

The goal is to make anime.js animate just when a user scrolls and stop animation when scrolling stops. The animations are different for up and down scrolling.
Here's the current code:

```
var focusDown, focusUp;
  var up = false, down = false, scrollPos = 0, scrollPos1;
  var isScrolling;
  window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
    window.clearTimeout( isScrolling );
    scrollPos1 = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scrollPos1 == scrollPos) {} else {
      if (scrollPos1 > scrollPos) {
        up = false;
        down = true;
      } else {
        up = true;
        down = false;
      }
    }
    scrollPos = scrollPos1;

    if (down) {
      focusDown = anime({
        targets: '.focus-text', easing: 'linear', duration: 20000, autoplay: false,
        translateX: function(el) {
          return $('.focus-text').offset().left + 500;
        }
      });
      focusDown.play();
    }
    if (up) {
      focusUp = anime({
        targets: '.focus-text', easing: 'linear', duration: 20000, autoplay: false,
        translateX: function(el) {
          return $('.focus-text').offset().left - 500;
        }
      });
      focusUp.play();
    }
    isScrolling = setTimeout(function() {
      if (focusUp && focusUp !== 'undefined') {focusUp.pause();}
      if (focusDown && focusDown !== 'undefined') {focusDown.pause();}
    }, 200);
  }, false);
```

[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/td8z3or4/1/)

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It does not work because you call  `window.clearTimeout( isScrolling );` on each `scroll` event. Suppose the browser fires two `scroll` events in 100ms then the first animation doesn't get paused because the function to pause it is cleared by the `clearTimeout` called by the second event.

In the end you could do without pausing, just adjust the duration and translation values

```
var duration = 200;
var offset = 50;

/*...*/

if (down) {
  focusDown = anime({
    targets: '.focus-text', easing: 'linear', duration: duration,
    translateX: function(el) {
      return $('.focus-text').offset().left + offset;
    }
  });
}
if (up) {
  focusUp = anime({
    targets: '.focus-text', easing: 'linear', duration: duration,
    translateX: function(el) {
      return $('.focus-text').offset().left - offset;
    }
  });
}
/*...*/
```